# Where is the official document of T-SQL abstract syntax tree?

Tags: .net, sql-server, abstract-syntax-tree

I use SqlParser class provided by SqlServer to parse the AST of a sql script,
like I answered in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34103965/3828013.

its output is a xml document like below. But I have searched a lot, and can not find any related document. Anyone knows can give me the link.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SqlScript Location="((1,1), (92,1))">
  <Errors />
  <SqlBatch Location="((91,3), (92,1))">
    <!--
-->
    <Tokens>
      <Token location="((91,3), (92,1))" id="651" type="LEX_WHITE">\n</Token>
    </Tokens>
  </SqlBatch>
</SqlScript>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the [SQL Abstract Syntax Trees Vocabulary](http://ns.inria.fr/ast/sql/index.html)

> Abstract syntax trees allow to build structured representations of
>   code for any language with a grammar: AST nodes carrying labels can
>   stand for keywords, objects, variables, constants or any language
>   element while the tree structure allows to abstract away the
>   language's concepts of scope or dependency. ASTs are a
>   machine-readable format for concrete syntax code, and can be decorated
>   with implicit or contextual knowledge from the grammar. We hereby
>   propose to model ASTs with RDF graphs. AST structures naturally fit
>   RDF graphs: nodes map resources, node labels map resources' types, and
>   grammar knowledge map to vocabulary's semantics, e.g. with
>   subsumption.

Comment: Appreciate your help. While seems that doc is for standard SQL. Is there any doc for MSSQL? Because I compared my generated AST xml to the doc you gave, still many differences.

Comment: @BartMao:- I dont think there is any official document by MSDN on Abstract syntax tree.